# Link Baselayerchange with Opacityslider

Tags: leaflet

I'm building a site to display historic maps, using the baselayer to display a single tilelayer on top of OSM/Google/Bing map. The tilelayer being selected from a radio button list using Control.Layers. I want to use the Control.Opacity plugin to adjust the transparency of the baselayer but I'm struggling to link the opacity control to the changing baselayer and will also need to filter out any changes to the background map.

Any suggestions?

Comment: After much head scratching I managed to find a solution,

Answer (score 2):

After some head scratching I managed to find a solution.

I use the baselayerchange event to capture the change, then filter the layer based on the name (I prefix the layer name with 'Map'). I then send the layer reference of the object to the opacityslide.

map.on('baselayerchange', function(e) 
{ if (e.name.slice(0,3)=="Map") {opacitySlider.setOpacityLayer(e.layer)}});

One more piece of feedback: when trying to reference kml files from a remote server I was receiving the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error message in Chrome. This I overcame by installing an extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

I hope that helps others with this problem :)